# Dictionary in Powershell on which I will iterate

Tags: powershell

I want to create a dictionary, on which later on I would like to iterate.
So the dictonary would look like this:

```
$dictionary = 
subnet |address
xyz | 10.1.2.0/24 
abc | 10.1.3.0/24
psh | 10.1.4.0/24
```

And i would like to iterate

```
foreach ($item in $dictionary){
$dmz = New-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $item.subnet -AddressPrefix $item.address


}
```

Does anyone knows how to create such a dictionary/table? As i am not really familiar with powershell, but I would like to create a simple script

Comment: You could use CSV data or a hashtable. How would you like to create this *dictionary*? ... by hand?

Comment: Yes, I want this script to create subnets, and whenever I would like to add more subnets, I just add it to dictionary( or hash-table).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using CSV data as they are the esiest to edit by hand

```
$dictionary = 
@'
subnet,address
"xyz","10.1.2.0/24" 
"abc","10.1.3.0/24"
"psh","10.1.4.0/24"
'@ | 
ConvertFrom-Csv

foreach ($item in $dictionary) {
    $dmz = New-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $item.subnet -AddressPrefix $item.address
}
```

Of course you could use a CSV file and import it with `Import-CSV`. This way you wouldn't need to edit the script itself. ;-)

Comment: Does this wrong correctly? If i do `echo "$item.subnet $item.address"` i get a weird output. Instead of just `xyz  10.1.2.0/24` i get `@{subnet =xyz; address=10.1.2.0/24}.subnet @{subnet =xyz; address=10.1.2.0/24}.address`

Comment: That's because you're using variable expansion inside a string. In your code example it works different. When you insist to use it this way you should use the subexpression operator `"$($item.subnet) $($item.address)"`

Answer (score 2):

To complement Olaf's working answer, here is an alternative way using a [`hashtable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.2) literal `@{…}`:

```sh
$dictionary = @{
    xyz = '10.1.2.0/24' 
    abc = '10.1.3.0/24'
    psh = '10.1.4.0/24'
}

foreach( $item in $dictionary.GetEnumerator() ) {
    $dmz = New-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $item.key -AddressPrefix $item.value
}
```

Note that the enumeration doesn't necessarily happen in order. If that is import, create an *ordered* `hashtable` instead:

```sh
$dictionary = [ordered] @{
    xyz = '10.1.2.0/24' 
    abc = '10.1.3.0/24'
    psh = '10.1.4.0/24'
}
```